# jQuery append and remove append

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add a clickable logo on every 5th side. On all other slides I don't want anything to appear beside the regular post content. So far this is the code I have. So far it works until it reached the 5th slide. On the 5th slide the logo appears, and it remains on the 6th, 7th and so on. I want it to only appear on the 5th, 10th, 15th etc. Any idea where I am going wrong?

```
jQuery(document).bind('theiaPostSlider.changeSlide', function(event, slideIndex) {
    var pad_count = tps_obj.pad_every_n_slides;
    var slide_num = slideIndex + 1;
    resultOfMod = slide_num % pad_count;
    if (resultOfMod == 0) {
        jQuery('.post-single-content').prepend('<a href="../index.html"><img src="../logo.jpg"></a>');
    } else {
        jQuery('.post-single-content').prepend('');
    }
}
```

Comment: give different ids to each slides to append & also please check your mod value..

Answer (score 0):

You must remove the logo when it changes to the 6th, 11th, 16th, etc or the logo will stay there and will appear.

If you have a single `a` element inside `.post-single-content`, use this:

Replace

```
jQuery('.post-single-content').prepend('');
```

With

```
jQuery('.post-single-content').remove('a');
```

---

If there's more two or more `a` element inside `.post-single-content`, you need to specify what element you want to remove, using this:

Replace

```
jQuery('.post-single-content').prepend('<a href="../index.html"><img src="../logo.jpg"></a>');
```

With

```
jQuery('.post-single-content').prepend('<a id="logo" href="../index.html"><img src="../logo.jpg"></a>');
```

**AND**

Replace

```
jQuery('.post-single-content').prepend('');
```

With

```
jQuery('.post-single-content').remove('#logo');
```

Comment: I tried the .remove tag with both methods you suggested but unfortunately its not removing the link/logo . Any other suggestions?

Comment: The .remove will work when `if (resultOfMod == 0)` is FALSE. Can you confirm that after the 5th, 10th, 15th... slide this condition will be FALSE?

Comment: Yes, I confirmed this by temporarily changing the remove to a different prepend image and on all other sides a different image is added. So I know the false condition is working. I just can't get the remove to work,